# Customizing serialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization

I have [***measured***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959119/undesrtanding-java-serialization) some serialization with JMH in Java and figured out it might be pretty slow and excessive.

Serialization mechanism provided by `ObjectOutputStream` is pretty general therefore might be slow. Is it possible to register a custom serialization protocol? `Externalizable` does not seem to be exactly what I want because it uses the same

```
void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException
void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
```

But I need the very custom protocol with some class headers ommited which is critical in my case. Is there a way to replace default serialization?

In short, I want to implement my own `ObjectOutputStream` and tell `JVM` to use it for some classes I annotated with some annotation like `@CustomSerializable`.

Comment: Just like you wrote, create own implementation of `ObjectOutputStream` and use it as wrapper to whatever output you wiil need (socke,file, another objecect stream etc). Insteed of trying to break internal mechanism, use your own custom serializer to transform object to byte[] or whatever

Comment: `register a custom serialization protocol?` register where?? `I want to implement my own ObjectOutputStream` what's stopping you? `and tell JVM to use it for some classes` what do you mean by that? You can write code that will do whatever you want.